# Hibernate and Glassfish config

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, configuration, glassfish

I'm working on project(REST) where I use hibernate with glassfish. I try to get list of data from DB, but I get this error:

```
  javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4021] (Eclipse Persistence                  Services - 2.0.1.v20100213-r6600): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Exception Description: Unable to acquire a connection from driver [null], user [null] and URL    [null].  Verify that you have set the expected driver class and URL.  Check your login, persistence.xml      or sessions.xml resource.  The jdbc.driver property should be set to a class that is compatible with    your database platform
note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish   Server Open Source Edition 3.0.1 logs.
```

PERSISTENCE.XML

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="manager1"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">

    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="false" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://url" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-update" />
```

UPDATE:

Connection to hibernate works, because I tested it in console.
Is it possible that Hibernate requires another config file for hibernate? 
Thanks for help :)

Comment: I think we need more info. Could you post your Persistent.xml ??

Comment: @AlexVaz I just added persistence.xml